# Vue2 - Computed property not updating on props changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I can't get a computed property to update, when a array element in a passed prop object is changed.

I have props in my component:

```
 props: {
    value: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    },

  }
```

In computed, i have:

```
computed: {
    indicators: {
      get() {
        return this.value;
      },

      set(value) {
        console.log('set');
        this.$emit('input', value);
      }
    },

    indicatorsWithTrand() {
      return this.indicators.filter((i) => i.trandCalculationEnabled);
    },

    indicatorWitOutTrand() {
      return this.indicators.filter((i) => !i.trandCalculationEnabled);
    }
  },
```

`indicatorsWithTrand` depends on `indicator`.

In my method i change `indicators` :

```
async getIndicatorRanges(indicator) {
      if (indicator.tempInitialValue && indicator.tempTargetValue) {
        const calculatedAnswerOptions = await this.$coreApi.calculateIndicatorRanges(
          indicator.id,
          this.selectedTemplateId,
          indicator.tempInitialValue,
          indicator.tempTargetValue
        );

        const updatedObject = {
          ...indicator,
          answerOptions: calculatedAnswerOptions
          // hasCalculatedRanges: true
        };

        const indicatorIndex = this.indicators.findIndex(
          (i) => i.id === indicator.id
        );

        this.indicators.splice(indicatorIndex, 1, updatedObject);

      }
```

But `indicatorsWithTrand` doesnt update after update `indicator`;

I tried some ways to update `indicator`, and use `$forceUpdate()`;

Comment: The computed setter only activates during assignment, e.g. `this.indicators = ...` not from in place updates which is what splice is doing. You're also splicing the `values` prop by doing that, because the array values are by reference, and mutating props is a bad practice.  You could try cloning the original array, splicing that, then assigning the cloned array back to the original. Properly setting new prop value may fix your computed issue.